# HLS Video Aspect Ratio changing on player resize

Tags: video-streaming, video.js, http-live-streaming

I'm testing out an HLS stream using videojs for a project I'm working on, and for some reason when the window is resized several times it seems that the stream changes to a 16:9 aspect ratio and after a few moments switches back to the aspect ratio set in the videojs instance.

In my case the aspect ratio is set to 256:239, and if the window is resized most times it results in the aspect ratio being changed with the video displaying like so:

[image]

The stream is via a 3rd party and although I am in communication with the 3rd party I've been told that the issue is not from their end. I'm not sure where the issue is to be honest, but after seeing this: [videojs/videojs-contrib-hls#305](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/issues/305) I'm lead to believe that it might be a similar issue. Are there any configurations from my end that I can set, or this is an issue from the stream itself?

I'm creating the video with the following settings:

```
this.player = videojs('video', {
    aspectRatio: '256:239',
    controls: true,
    autoplay: false,
    muted: true,
    html5: {
        hls: {
            overrideNative: true
        }
    }
});
```

I have created a stackblitz to replicate the issue and the same thing is happening: https://stackblitz.com/edit/videojs-hls-issue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fvideo%2Fvideo.component.ts

Version Numbers:

- VideoJS version 7.5.0
- Although it might be irrelevant, since this is an Angular application I'm also using the VideoJS Typings version 7.2.8

Furthermore I've tested this on Angular 5.2.8 as well as Angular 7.2.4 and the issue seems to occur more frequent on macOS.

Comment: >>>the issue seems to occur more frequent on macOS..  My hunch before seeing that, was that the symptom sounds like it could be a browser-specific issue.  How many different browsers have you tested this on?

Comment: I've tested this both on Windows and Mac... same thing is happening on Chrome and Firefox as well as Safari.